# Data Validation should be done at Request Level or in Middleware using expressjs?

Tags: node.js, validation

I have API endpoints that accept some data either using GET, POST , PUT and DELETE. I want to know which is the best place to validate the incoming data? Is it Endpoint (request level) or in the middleware for expressjs? I want to know what are the advantages and disadvantages for both places for performance wise and security?

I look [JOI(Object schema validation)](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) node js library which does at request level whereas [Express-validator](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator) does at middleware.

Comment: IMO Validation should be done earliest as possible, regarding the performance. Earlier you discard the request as invalid, less code is invoked. As for the security, I think it does not have any side effect.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the changes? How much effort is required for a change to introduce data validation in already devaloped project using at request level or in middleware?

Comment: If you have your project structured properly, it should not be a difficult task. You probably have a router file, and inside it you could implement the validation.